# I'm using the Sublime text3 and SVN package. How do I change default commit message?

Tags: svn, sublimetext3, commit, setting

When commit file or folder in Sublime text SVN, default commit message is has set "Type commit message here…".

How do I change this message?

Comment: Have you read the fine [documentation](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/svn)?

Comment: yes i have but i didn't found explication that set SVN commit message

Comment: There isn't a setting for changing it because you're supposed to type your own commit message in it's place. That's why the text says "Type commit message here..." in the first place. It's even selected by default so all you have to do is start typing in order to replace it.

Comment: Really useful would be to find the previous commit message by default or the ability to scroll through the commit messages history.